# How do I make a variable output 3 results constantly during cycle iteration?

Tags: c++

I need these numbers `1`, `1000`, `1000000` without stopping in the cycle

```
1
1000
1000000
1
1000
1000000
1
1000
1000000
...
```

Comment: Yes, and...? What was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: Do you know how to output one number in one line?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I tried to do it using `%` but it didn't work

Comment: Please show a [mre] of what you tried and what exactly the problem was. If you got an error message, please show it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 and what is not clear the `i` variable will output first `1` then `1000` then `1000000`

Comment: Maybe you should assign the numbers 1, 1000, 1000000 to i?

Answer (score 3):

From the question I see no restriction that you should print only one row per list iteration, so you could just print all three of them in the same iteration:

```
for(;;) { // cycle do not touch
    cout << 1 << endl << 1000 << endl << 1000000 << endl;
}
```

Comment: your version doesn't fit

Comment: @tomi The above code is doing exactly what you asked for. Or what it seems to be your request..